# matrix sql from CASE substr

Tags: sql, matrix, case, substr

I have a question about my select , I have to create Attributes like columns , but i dont know how to do that becouse its a substring with When and Then , It is possible to use AS keyword for create Attributes . My explenation is funny, but this the only way how can i subscribe my problem. THX a lot

```
    CASE    
    when substr (CETYK9, 1, 2) = 11 AS 'C_TRX_MC_ONUS'
    when substr(cetyk9,1,2) in (12,13) AND (CDPAIS ='703') AS 'C_TRX_MC_NOTONUS'
    when substr(cetyk9,1,2) in (14,16) AS 'C_TRX_MC_INTER'
    when substr (CETYK9, 1, 2) = 21 AS 'C_TRX_VISA_ONUS'         
    when substr(cetyk9,1,2) in (22,23) AND (CDPAIS='SK') AS 'C_TRX_VISA_NOTONUS'
    when substr(cetyk9,1,2) in (24,26) AS 'C_TRX_VISA_INTER'
    when substr (CETYK9, 1, 2) = 56 AS 'C_TRX_DC_INTER'
    end DIFF*/
```

Comment: Are those supposed to be different columns?  If so, then you can create a separate `CASE` for each column.

Comment: Another option to consider is a look up table and then just join to it by the first two chars and then pivot

Comment: Thank you very much , can you write only for the first CASE , how to create different columns , i think this a good solution